# Image is South up while converting NetCDF layer to GTiff with gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, gdal-translate, osgeo

Issue: I'm trying to extract a NetCDF layer to GeoTIFF. The output GeoTIFF image has the South up.

What I need: The output GeoTIFF image with North up.

GDAL version: 3.2.2, released 2021/03/05; OS: Windows 10

The test NetCDF file (~42 mb) is available from [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gn2qgbznvi5tv4/test.nc?dl=0):

Code:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot float32 -a_nodata none -strict -q -unscale -co TFW=yes -a_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:test.nc:chlor_a_diff test.tif
```

The output GeoTIFF image has the South up:
[image]

So far, I have tried:

1. creation option: `-co GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=NO`. This creation option is not recognized
2. Used NumPy (np.rot90, with k=2): it did not help.

I might be missing something more fundamental.

How to get the image with North up?

Comment: Looks like they has the same problem (https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/Q5UCVE) see the metadata, they used the ArcGIS FLip tool

Comment: Thanks for adding to the discussion. I have used an alternative approach as stated in my comments below simply using Python and it worked with the same efficiency as it would with direct GDAL use. Trying to stick to open source resources as I am not conversant with ArcGIS but I am sure it must be efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 NETCDF:test.nc:chlor_a_diff test.tif
```

Original file:

```
print(gdal.Open('test.nc').GetGeoTransform())
=> (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 NETCDF:test.nc:chlor_a_diff test.tif
print(gdal.Open('test.tif').GetGeoTransform())
=> (-180.0, 0.020830922346950585, 0.0, 90.0, 0.0, -0.020884093282283328)
```

The TIFF has the correct sign for the dY and starts from +90 latitude. It also has reasonable pixel spacings. But it looks flipped left to right when zoomed out. When zoomed in, it looks OK. In tha maps below, it is displayed ***above*** the OSM basemap, which looks encouraging.

#### Zoomed In

[image]

#### UK Area

[image]

It looks quite chloroful.

#### Zoomed Out

[image: Is this flipped from left to right?]

Comment: Thank you, but I still have the same issue - the South up if I simply view the output TIF in a desktop image viewer. (I cannot attach an image in this comment).

Please note that the georeferencing is not wrong in the original post; only that the map starts displaying -90 on top and the North-South increment is positive.

About the mismatch between OSM and your map, it is likely because of EPSG 3857 (OSM) and this map (EPSG 4326). So, that is expected.

Are you using QGIS to show the map? If yes, QGIS somehow orients it as desired.

Comment: GeoTiff images are generally stored top-down. QGIS orients it with its embedded GeoTransform. By flipping the transform, it displays correctly in QGIS as mentioned earlier. That won't change its appearance in an image viewer if the viewer ignores the transform of course, or if both the raster and the transform are flipped. If you just want to flip the raster data, np.flipud() might help. Are you trying to display this in an image viewer or a GIS?

Comment: I figured it out but had to use an alt approach. The issue is due to 2 things: (a) the way the NetCDF file is written even if it is CF1.6 compliant (b) gdal_translate's precision check for lat/lon. This particular file was detected to have non-uniform lat increment by 'gdal_translate' and some built-in mechanism kicks in. SOLUTION: I just read the NetCDF in Python, extract lat, lon, data, perform necessary steps & write to GeoTIFF using osgeo/gdal (from osgeo import gdal)- not the command line gdal. Some info on GeoTIFF generation with this approach is here http://drr.ikcest.org/tutorial/k8024

Comment: That should work. I take it you flipped the raster. Does it display correctly in a GIS?

Comment: Yes, it displays correctly on GIS viewer, e.g., QGIS. I did not have to flip the data array but define the 6 elements correctly in Geotransform. Due to the precision issue in GDAL_TRANSLATE, it internally does something and the 'yres' is changed.
I set it as:
  """
 Define the six line element for geotransformation
    top-left x
    west-east pixel resolution
    rotation (0 if North is up)
    top-left y
    rotation (0 if North is up)
    north-south pixel resolution
  """
geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)
Then write the output tiff as in the link in my prev answer.

Comment: That's what the -a_ullr does :-)

Comment: True, except that, as it seems, when gdal_translate detects lat or lon having non-uniform increment (due to precision enforcement), it resets something internally and the external -a_ullr specification does not take effect the orientation anymore. Something is unclear but with the manual approach, we have better control.

Comment: There is no non-uniform increment in a GeoTiff, by definition. There is a GeoTransform, which contains a fixed dx and dy. This is important to understand. Otherwise, almost all GeoTiffs would fail to load, as very few have neat increments. An incorrect GeoTransform is typically the problem. Using -a_ullr changes it so that it flips. A new dx and dy are calculated. That is what is reset internally. The raster itself is not changed at all. Try my example again. I think you'll see what I'm saying,

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware and this discussion is in the wrong direction now. I wrote: "gdal detects ... due to precision ...". It does not mean, it's non-uniform in reality. And the raster is obviously not changed at all or flipped.

GDAL warning from my first line of code: "Warning 1: Latitude grid not spaced evenly.  Setting projection for grid spacing is within 0.1 degrees threshold.". This is the issue and when this happens, the a_ullr does not help any more.

Comment: I used the same dataset you did. I entered "gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 NETCDF:test.nc:chlor_a_diff test.tif" and had no issues. What command did you use?

Comment: Interesting, exactly the same as yours. Usually, I don't use '-a_ullr -180 90 180 -90' if the input nc is in EPSG4326 and the bounds same as above. As you suggested, I used the 'a_ullr' arg to check. Yet, the output TIF is South up, in contrast to your result. Perhaps, GDAL ver/OS behavioral diff, I'm not sure anymore. My OS is Win 10 and GDAL is: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal (GDAL‑3.2.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl).
But the Python+NetCDF4 +osgeo/gdal approach works and takes the same time. So, this should be okay in our oper processing. The WMTS tiles look fine too. Thanks

Comment: Many ways to do the same thing :-) NetCDF seems to be a little painful to load into a GIS.